# Im trying to build a coffee locator app using google places api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Thanks for the help geocode ive made the changes but i'm still having the same issues, im sorry to bore you with petty mistakes but ill post the code below if you have time

```html
 <html lang="en">
     <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale1.0, user-scalable no">
          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyBxa8x1c5vnQZr95sqld_ZYT_1hM7yVNxU"> 
         <script> var map;
          function initialize() {
  var center = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5044672, -0.0821554);
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: center,
    zoom: 13
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding;
  0px
}

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map">
</div>
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
    <div id="map">
    </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of comments in the YouTube video are saying they are getting a blank page maybe you need a new Google API Key.

Source:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Comment: Sorry, im a noob at stackoverflow too it seems

Comment: Damnit i still got nothing

Answer (score 0):

There are several syntax errors in the posted code:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` on this line:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load' initialize);
```

(missing a "," between 'load' and initialize)

and:

`Uncaught TypeError: google.maps.latlng is not a constructor` on this line:

```
var center = new google.maps.latlng(51.5044672,-0.0821554);
```

(javascript is case sensitive, the correct version is `LatLng` not `latlng`)

and:

`Uncaught TypeError: document.getelementById is not a function` and `Uncaught TypeError: google.maps.map is not a constructor` on this line:

```
map = new google.maps.map(document.getelementById('map'), {
```

(javascript is case sensitive, the correct version is `getElementById` not `getelementById` and `google.maps.map` should be `google.maps.Map`

If I fix those, I get a map [(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/qLtqurh8/), but there is no "coffee locator" functionality in the posted code.

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var center = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5044672, -0.0821554);
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: center,
    zoom: 13
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding;
  0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, i appreciate the help greatly

Comment: If this answered your question please [accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: I thought geocodezip answered it? The code geocodezip provided is working. Also the previous link you gave us was Coffee APP making tutorial "PART 2" , and from what I saw from the video previously linked it only teaches you how to setup a map. So I would highly suggest you accept geocodezip's answer (you will also get 2 rep for accepting his answer).

Comment: Wilco. going to do it